# Yii2 framework drag and drop extension HTML5 input

Tags: yii2

I need to move checkbox selected contents from one div to the other using the >> selector in yii2 framework. For example i have a list of programming language skills in one container, i need to allow the candidate to select the skills from one container and after clicking on the >> button the selected skills should move to another div.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php

echo Sortable::widget([ 'connected'=>true, 
    'items'=>[ 
        ['content'=>'C++'],
        ['content'=>'Java'],
        ['content'=>'MYSQL'],
        ['content'=>'SEO'],
    ] 
]); 

echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>'; 

echo Sortable::widget([ 'connected'=>true, 'itemOptions'=>['class'=>'alert alert-warning'], 'items'=>[ [], [], [], [], ] ]);

echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';

?>
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far

Comment: please add the code in the Question by editing it

Comment: Hi, i think this can help you [multi-select](http://loudev.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  that you need is the  dual list box extension  , read the documentation [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-dual-list-box/)

This will see like that

[image]